# Custom Field to show when an Item has broken role inheritance

Tags: custom-field-types, inheritance

I had to realize a Custom Field to show when the associated Item has broken role inheritance...

I see 2 ways to do that:

- Read just in time if the Item has broken role inheritance
- Derive a Boolean SP Field and keep the value inside of it

I think the first way is more efficent (also because I must not implement an Event Handler on Item Check In or something like that)...

How can I access to the SPListItem from a custom field? Is there any method or suggested practice?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

The custom field basically uses [BaseFieldControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.basefieldcontrol_members) to show field value. This class has two templates for control rendering - DefaultTemplateName (for new/edit form) and DisplayTemplateName (for display form). You can try to create these templates and override **Value** method of **BaseFieldControl**. In this method you should have access to the **Item** property of **BaseFieldControl**. If the microsoft documentation is correct this property provides [SPItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitem_members) object that has [HasUniqueRoleAssignments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurableobject.hasuniqueroleassignments) flag for indicating whether the object has unique role assignments or inherits its role assignments from a parent object.

For example:

```
public override object Value
{
    get
    {
        _control = TemplateContainer.FindControl("controlId");
        _control.Visible = Item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments;

        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        base.Value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works with the BaseFieldControl, but I need it during the display in listviewwebpart..

Comment: it is much easier. Look [this post](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/04/overriding-the-presentation-of-an-xslt-list-view-web-part.html). You can use the same approach.

Comment: Yes it's the way I follow to create it... But now I have a boolean value and I modify it whenever I modify the permission on the file by 2 custom ribbon actions... I can't face how I can get the item from the SPFieldText that I'm extending without using the BaseFieldControl item

Comment: If I understand correctly, in your case the best way is to use class that is inherited from [SPFieldBoolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldboolean.aspx) class. This field should be set from code by your custom actions. For this field you can set BaseFieldControl and use `_control.Visible = value`. if you need to customize list view you can use Glyn post. In your xsl your should check boolean value of this field and show or not labels.